# Typescript - How to dynamically add methods to class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I need to declare types for a class, for example:

```
class Editor extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
   value: object;
}
```

Now I have combined type (could also be an interface) of methods from another library:

```
type onHistory<T> = {
   save(): T
}


type onSelection<T> = {
   flip(): T
}

type methods = onHistory<Editor> & onSelection<Editor>
```

Is there any clean way to append all the methods (save, flip... and 300 other in my case) dynamically without manually copy/pasting them?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to monkey-patch?

Comment: I'm trying to write types for a library that uses Mixins.

Comment: I am struggling to understand your intent. And adding 300 methods to a class isn't feasible either. You'd need a code generator and most likely a difference architecture / design altogether. Please elaborate your actual use case further.

Comment: Im not the author of the actual library.